# Send mail ruby (gmail with net/smtp)

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, gmail

I have this code:

```
   @msg = "Subject: Hi There!\nThis works."
    smtp = Net::SMTP.new 'smtp.gmail.com', 587
    smtp.enable_starttls
    smtp.start(YourDomain, YourAccountName, YourPassword, :login)
      smtp.send_message(@msg, FromAddress, ToAddress)
    end
```

But i wonder what the mean with YourDomain?! I want to send from gmail is that then "gmail.com" for my yourdomain?
I am confused, i have send emails with C#, php and actionscript but i never had to enter a domain or i cannot remember it!

OK it was a stupid question of me, it has to be "gmail.com"! It works, just a typo (shame on my!)

Answer (score 2):

It means the domain that identifies you and is sent with the HELO command to the smtp server (gmail in your case).

If you don't have a domain, you can use an address literal (see [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.3)). In your case I guess you could use [your_ip]

Anyway, it is often ignored by the smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it means "What's domain your want to?"